# Is not the way I want PartialViewResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, product, using, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I try something.I apologize in advance for my english.

My Action code;

```
public PartialViewResult showProduct()
{

    var query = db.Categories.Where((c) => c.CategoryID == 4);
    return PartialView("_EditCategory",query);
}
```

My view code:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "showProduct",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
        UpdateTargetId = "result"
    }))
    {
       <input type="submit" value="Get" />
    }
    <div id="result">
    </div>
```

When i pushed the submit button ( which value is get) the results return but in another page like http://localhost:57616/Home/showProduct but i want return to result div in index page.

Any one can help me?

Answer (score 1):

So, how I handled this myself was something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var options = {
   target: "#mytargetdiv",
   url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "IceCream")',
};

$("#editIceCreamForm").submit(function () {
   $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
   return false;
}

// other stuff

});
```

in other places, where I wanted to do in-place editing of things I'd do something like this:

```
<input type="button" id="someid" value="Edit" data-someid="@Model.SomeId"/>
```

and then some ajax like so:

```
$(function () {
   $("#someid".click(function () {
      var theId = $(this).data('someid');
      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         data: "id=" + theId,
         url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "Something")',
         dataType: "html",
         success: function (result) {
            $('#targetdiv').html(result);
         }
      });
   });
});
```

---

So, if you're not interested in using jQuery and want to use the MS Ajax stuff, are you including the MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js files on the page?  If you don't have those, I believe what will happen is it just does the default (non-Ajax) submit.

Comment: I dont want with javascript :(

Comment: See my added note at bottom of answer.